# A field $K\subset \Bbb{C}$ such that $[\Bbb{C}:K]=2$ but $K$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, real-numbers

**Is there a field $K\subset \Bbb{C}$ such that $[\Bbb{C}:K]=2$ but $K$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$ ?**

Unless I'm wrong, under the axiom of choice there should be an isomorphism $\sigma: \bigcup_{n\ge 1} \Bbb{C}((x^{1/n}))\to \Bbb{C}$ so that $K=\sigma(\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\Bbb{R}((x^{1/n})))$ works.

Comment: By the Artin-Schreier Theorem, $K$ must be a real closed field.

Comment: (There might be a better duplicate target but that was the best I could find after several minutes of searching.)